# Drawing bipartite graph

Tags: graphs

I want to draw graphs with white and black vertices, such as square-octagon graph. Someone knows the easy way to draw in Latex? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did u look at `tikz`? or `pgfplots` depending on the graph type.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends in part on how much time and effort you're willing to put into it. Definitely start by looking at tikz along with the `tkz-graph` package [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-graph) and the `tkz-berge` package [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-berge). [This site](http://graphtheoryinlatex.wordpress.com/) and [this page](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/) are a good place to start looking at for examples which you like best. Make sure you read Altermundus' "Gallery of Named Graphs"; you can download it [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.altermundus.fr%2Fdownloads%2Fdocuments%2FNamedGraphs.pdf&ei=XzPDUZz6DJDO9gS9_oHoAw&usg=AFQjCNGvwk0ezzts7Vc2JaNRPVcJgykJHA&bvm=bv.48175248,d.eWU). Note that the computer algebra system Sage supports tikz and Altermundus' packages as well as LaTeX. The relevant page is [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_latex.html?highlight=graph%20tikz). Robert Beezer has used Sage combined with LaTeX to produce graphs; see [here](http://buzzard.ups.edu/sage.html) for example.

Comment: There is an introductory video on using Sage for graph theory [here](http://vimeo.com/14046039). It will give you an idea of the power Sage will give you.