# Package to draw graphs (not graphics) by mathematical desciptions

Tags: graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

Is there any latex package to draw graphs by its descriptive relations. Lets say:

`\draw_graph_complete{5}{1}`

Or

`\draw_graph{u,v,x,y,z}{{u,v}{v,x}{x,z}{y,z}}`

I don't want to deal with placement coordinates or stuff like that.

So far I have found the `tikz` libraries as `graphs` and `graphs.standard`.

For example this MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={circle, draw}, grow right=2cm, branch down=2cm]{
      b,
      a -- {b,c},
      c -- {b},
      e -- {a,d},
      d -- {c}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives a nice graph, but lacks symmetry in the node `b`. I can live with that, but looking for alternatives.

Comment: If you want to draw a complete graph or other standard graphs, doesn't `graphs.standard` do what you need? (I realize it doesn't for the non-standard graph that you provided in your code.)

Comment: See my answer for the question posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120236/drawing-bipartite-graph/120248#120248). Basically, you want to use tikz in combination with the `tkz-graph`, and `tkz-berge` packages and you should look into `sagetex` with Sage. Links are provided to get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the question is more how to know which algorithm to employ. I do not have a general answer but in this case you may want to do

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing, graphs.standard}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[spring layout,
nodes={circle, draw}, ]{
      b,
      a -- {b,c},
      c -- {b},
      e -- {a,d},
      d --[orient=90] {c}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This places `b` more symmetrically.