# Drawing Pictures in LaTeX

Tags: graphs, draw, technical-drawing

I want to know the methods and packages for drawing directly in latex. I work mostly in Overleaf. I want to draw graph-theoretic figures directly.

Comment: Look here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package

Comment: For instance, the pgfmanual has a huge chapter on graph drawing: **IV Graph Drawing**.

Comment: An article about drawing graph has been prepared [here](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/joshi/joshi.pdf).

Comment: You should look at `tkz-graph` and `tkz-berge` package. For more complex graph theoretic material, consider the `sagetex` package. My answer for [Drawing a bipartite graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120236/drawing-bipartite-graph/120248#120248) has more detail and links. See my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367694/can-i-draw-my-graphs-graph-theory-with-tikz-online/367719#367719) as well.